# Getting all TaskAttempts of a Task from Hadoop API

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

I would like to get information on **all** TaskAttempts of a Task of a Job on Hadoop.

org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskReport gives information on running Attempts and successful Attempts, but I would like to also get those that failed or were killed. Any nice way of doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `keep.failed.task.files` to `true`.